# Compute distributional Fourier transform of cos^4(x)

Tags: distribution-theory

The goal is to compute $\hat{f}[\varphi]$ for $f=cos^4(x)$ and $\varphi \in \mathscr{S\mathbb{(R}})$ (Schwartz-Space)

My plan was to switch integrals with Fubini (since $\varphi \in \mathscr{S(\mathbb{R})} $ we have $\hat\varphi \in \mathscr{S(\mathbb{R})} $ and hence $\int_\mathbb{R\times\mathbb{R}}|cos^4(x)\varphi(k)e^{-ikx}|dxdk<\infty$ )

$$\hat{f}[\varphi]=f[\hat{\varphi}]=\int_\mathbb{R} cos^4(x) \hat\varphi(x) dx=\int_\mathbb{R}cos^4(x) \int_\mathbb{R}\varphi(k)e^{-ikx}dk \, dx \overset{Fubini}{=} \int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}cos^4(x)e^{-ikx}dx \right)\varphi(k)dk=  \frac{1}{2^4} \int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^4e^{-ikx}dx \right)\varphi(k)dk=...=\int_\mathbb{R}g(k) \varphi(k)dk=g[\varphi] \Rightarrow \hat f=g$$
but I don't see how to fill the dots since by developing the binomial $(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^4=e^{4ix}+4e^{2ix}+6+4e^{-2ix}+e^{-4ix}$ I get non-integrable functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, that (at least without using lots of imagination) the change of order of integration is not legitimate, and the computation gets stuck. We have to treat $\cos^4 x$ as a tempered distribution, as you anticipate.

As you anticipate, expressing
$$\cos^4 x\;=\;\Big({1\over 2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})\Big)^4\;=\;{1\over 2^4}(e^{4ix}+4e^{2ix}+6+4e^{-2ix}+e^{-4ix})
$$
in terms of exponentials helps isolate the issues: it suffices to determine the Fourier transform of (the tempered distribution) $e^{icx}$, with real $c$. Of course, trying to do this directly runs into a similar issue as you already found.

One way or another, we might know/anticipate that Fourier transforms of (purely imaginary) exponentials are (constant multiples of) translates of Dirac $\delta$. Thus, to pin down some of the details/constants, we compute the *inverse* Fourier transform of "$\delta(x-x_o)$", meaning $\delta$ translated by $x_o$, even though pointwise values do not make sense.

A worthwhile point regarding rigor is that, since $\delta(x-x_o)$ is a compactly-supported distribution, its inverse Fourier transform is (up to normalization) obtained just by evaluating it on exponentials:
$$
\check{\delta}(x-x_o)(\xi)\;=\;\delta(x-x_o)(e^{ix\xi})
\;=\; e^{ix_o\xi}
$$
Maybe you want to divide by $2\pi$ or $\sqrt{2\pi}$, depending on your normalization. By Fourier inversion for tempered distributions, up to the $2\pi$ normalization stuff,
$$
\widehat{e^{ix_o x}} \;=\; \delta(x-x_o)
$$
So the Fourier transform of $\cos^4 x$ is a linear combination of $\delta(x-4)$, $\delta(x-2)$, $\delta(x)$, $\delta(x+2)$. and $\delta(x+4)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **non-integrable function**!
$$\int a.e^{rx} dx = a/r. e^{rx}$$
Regardless of
$r \in \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$.

$$\int (e^{4ix} + 4e^{2ix} + 6 + 4e^{-2ix} + e^{-4ix})dx
= \int ((e^{4ix} + e^{-4ix}) + 4(e^{2ix} + e^{-2ix}) + 6)dx$$
$$= \int (2\cos(4x) + 8\cos(2x) + 6)dx =
1/2.\sin(4x) + 4.\sin(2x) + 6.x + C$$

Comment: In class we defined a function $f:E \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to be integrable $\iff \int_E |f| < \infty$ . I admit this confuses me and I'm not sure what to think about this. In any case I don't see how to compute the integral above with respect to x, because it does not converge over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I just convert imaginary part to real equivalence, I hope it help.
Also check if you must whether compute the integration over all domain or one period only.

Comment: It really is over $\mathbb{R}$. Modulo the possibly improper use of the word integrable your right hand side shows that the integral does not converge, which is the whole point of my question.